# How to add spacing between polylines in svg?

Tags: css, svg, polyline

I want to add spacing between two polylines. How can I add spacing between the polylines?

I've tried to add the polylines in seperates svg, that didn't help.

```html
<svg class="svg-container">
<polyline fill="none" points="0,1 30,1 30,42" style="stroke:green"></polyline>
<polyline fill="none" points="30,49 30,82 0,82" style="stroke:green"></polyline>
</svg>
```

I expect spacing between the two polylines, but the actual output are close to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that: in points attribute in  `polyLine`: it's represented as:

x1,y1 x2,y2 .. etc

You can see in first polyLine:

2nd Coordinate: 30 for x, and 1for y

3rd Coordinate: 30 for x, and 42 for y

Notice that the y coordinate changed by 41.

So for second `polyLine` first  y coordinate should start from:

42 (the previous coordinate) + 41 (to make equal space distance) = 83

You can now continue 2nd and 3rd coordinate with some calculations.

Working Example:

```html
<svg class="svg-container">
<polyline fill="none" points="0,1 30,1 30,42" style="stroke:green"></polyline>
<polyline fill="none" points="30,83 30,124 0,124" style="stroke:green"></polyline>
</svg>
```

Comment: This look more like it :) thanks
Do you know where I can read more about this? :)

Comment: What i do is to change the points in polyline i'll  edit the answer to describe it

Comment: That seems much more tedious than using a transform.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've added more description to answer if you want to check it

Answer (score 1):

Just try this. it may work for you.

```html
<svg class="svg-container">
 <polyline fill="none" points="0,1 30,1 30,30" style="stroke:green"></polyline>
 <polyline fill="none" points="30,49 30,82 0,82" style="stroke:green"></polyline>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute) to move things about. E.g.

```html
<svg class="svg-container">
<polyline fill="none" points="0,1 30,1 30,42" style="stroke:green"></polyline>
<polyline transform="translate(0, 13)" fill="none" points="30,49 30,82 0,82" style="stroke:green"></polyline>
</svg>
```